# Weird glitch in Chrome 81+ when body is set to 100%

Tags: css, google-chrome

Our website has been working great for years, but for some reason latest Chrome version 81 introduced a new bug. I'm setting body height to 100% to be able to use sticky footer (footer on bottom of the screen if content is short). But now it seems that that setting causes navi items below screen height (visible when scrolling down) to glitch when hovering them.

Also this glitch disappears when I resize the browser window, and won't appear anymore until I reload the page.

Disabling 100% body height resolves this, but then my footer is no longer sticky, meaning pages that are short in height, will push footer right after content. Besides, that way the another glitch happens below the footer.

Can anyone point me in the right direction how to solve this? Example page is https://www.stll.fi/liitto/

Comment: Your example page doesn't load. Please check the URL.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @BryceHowitson URL is correct. If it doesn't load for anyone abroad, then it would be a big problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by disabling sticky-footer behavior on page load, when no scrollbar is in use.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)/)) {
      if ($(document).height() > $(window).height()) {
         $('body').css('height', 'auto');
      }
   }
});
```

**EDIT**: This was an actual bug in Chrome, and has been fixed in the latest Chrome update.